# Implementation of static_vector using an array of std::aligned_storage, with std::launder and forwarding

Tags: c++, memory-management, template, c++17, sfinae

I'm trying to expand on the implementation of static_vector on the `std::aligned_storage` [reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), but would like to split it into two parts. First, an `aligned_storage_array` that supports perfect forwarding (so that I can emplace into it) and doesn't require a default constructor, and then the actual `static_vector` infrastructure that builds upon it. This will let me use the `aligned_storage_array` for some other static data structures I plan to make in the future.

**aligned_storage_array.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace nonstd
{
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    class aligned_storage_array
    {
    public:
        aligned_storage_array()  = default;
        ~aligned_storage_array() = default;

        // Move and copy must be manually implemented per-element by the user
        aligned_storage_array(aligned_storage_array&& rhs)                 = delete;
        aligned_storage_array& operator=(aligned_storage_array&& rhs)      = delete;
        aligned_storage_array(const aligned_storage_array& rhs)            = delete;
        aligned_storage_array& operator=(const aligned_storage_array& rhs) = delete;

        // Size
        constexpr std::size_t size() const noexcept { return N; }
        constexpr std::size_t max_size() const noexcept { return N; }

        // Access
        inline T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
        {
            return *std::launder(
                reinterpret_cast<T*>(
                    std::addressof(m_data[pos])));
        }

        inline const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
        {
            return *std::launder(
                reinterpret_cast<const T*>(
                    std::addressof(m_data[pos])));
        }

        inline T& at(std::size_t pos)
        {
            return *std::launder(
                reinterpret_cast<T*>(
                    std::addressof(m_data.at(pos))));
        }

        inline const T& at(std::size_t pos) const
        {
            return *std::launder(
                reinterpret_cast<const T*>(
                    std::addressof(m_data.at(pos))));
        }

        // Operations
        template<typename ...Args>
        inline T& emplace(size_t pos, Args&&... args)
        {
            return
                *::new(std::addressof(m_data[pos]))
                T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        template<typename ...Args>
        inline T& bounded_emplace(size_t pos, Args&&... args)
        {
            return
                *::new(std::addressof(m_data.at(pos)))
                T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }

        inline void destroy(std::size_t pos)
        {
            std::destroy_at(
                std::launder(
                    reinterpret_cast<const T*>(
                        std::addressof(m_data[pos]))));
        }

        inline void bounded_destroy(std::size_t pos)
        {
            std::destroy_at(
                std::launder(
                    reinterpret_cast<const T*>(
                        std::addressof(m_data.at(pos)))));
        }

    private:
        std::array<std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>, N> m_data;
    };
}
```

**static_vector.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "aligned_storage_array.h"

namespace nonstd
{
    template<class T, std::size_t N>
    class static_vector
    {
    public:
        using value_type      = T;
        using pointer         = T*;
        using const_pointer   = const T*;
        using reference       = value_type&;
        using const_reference = const value_type&;
        using iterator        = value_type*;
        using const_iterator  = const value_type*;
        using size_type       = std::size_t;

        static_vector() = default;
        ~static_vector() { clear(); }

        static_vector(const static_vector& rhs)
        {
            clear(); // Sets m_size to zero for safety
            for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < rhs.m_size; ++pos)
                m_data[pos] = rhs.m_data[pos];
            m_size = rhs.m_size;
        }

        static_vector& operator=(const static_vector& rhs)
        {
            if (this != std::addressof(rhs))
            {
                clear(); // Sets m_size to zero for safety
                for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < rhs.m_size; ++pos)
                    m_data[pos] = rhs.m_data[pos];
                m_size = rhs.m_size;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        static_vector(static_vector&& rhs)
        {
            // Start by clearing sizes to avoid bad data
            // access in the case of an exception
            std::size_t count_self = m_size;
            std::size_t count_rhs = rhs.m_size;
            m_size = 0;
            rhs.m_size = 0;

            // Can't swap because the destination may be uninitialized
            destroy_n(count_self);
            for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < count_rhs; ++pos)
                m_data[pos] = std::move(rhs.m_data[pos]);
            m_size = count_rhs;
        }

        static_vector& operator=(static_vector&& rhs)
        {
            // Start by clearing sizes to avoid bad data
            // access in the case of an exception
            std::size_t count_self = m_size;
            std::size_t count_rhs = rhs.m_size;
            m_size = 0;
            rhs.m_size = 0;

            // Can't swap because the destination may be uninitialized
            destroy_n(count_self);
            for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < count_rhs; ++pos)
                m_data[pos] = std::move(rhs.m_data[pos]);
            m_size = count_rhs;
            return *this;
        }

        // Size and capacity
        constexpr std::size_t size()      const { return m_size; }
        constexpr std::size_t max_size()  const { return N; }
        constexpr bool empty()            const { return m_size == 0; }

        // Iterators
        inline iterator begin()                 { return &m_data[0]; }
        inline const_iterator begin()     const { return &m_data[0]; }
        inline iterator end()                   { return &m_data[m_size]; }
        inline const_iterator end()       const { return &m_data[m_size]; }

        // Access
        inline T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
        {
            return m_data[pos];
        }

        inline const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const
        {
            return m_data[pos];
        }

        inline T& at(std::size_t pos)
        {
            if ((pos < 0) || (pos >= m_size))
                throw std::out_of_range("static_vector subscript out of range");
            return m_data[pos];
        }

        inline const T& at(std::size_t pos) const
        {
            if ((pos < 0) || (pos >= m_size))
                throw std::out_of_range("static_vector subscript out of range");
            return m_data[pos];
        }

        // Operations
        template<typename ...Args>
        inline T& emplace_back(Args&&... args)
        {
            T& result = m_data.bounded_emplace(m_size, args...);
            ++m_size;
            return result;
        }

        inline void clear()
        {
            std::size_t count = m_size;
            m_size = 0; // In case of exception
            destroy_n(count);
        }

    private:
        void destroy_n(std::size_t count)
        {
            for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < count; ++pos)
                m_data.destroy(pos);
        }

        aligned_storage_array<T, N> m_data;
        std::size_t m_size = 0;
    };
}
```

A full testing apparatus is available [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bvq4dcHHL3vQK95m) (wandbox). Mostly I'd like some extra eyes to help determine:

1. Is this *actually* safe for placement new with respect to alignment?
2. Is the use of `std::launder` correct?
3. Is the use of `reinterpret_cast` correct (or should it be two `static_cast`s instead?)
4. Are there any hidden pitfalls I should watch out for here (aside from the maximum capacity)?
5. Am I being sufficiently paranoid (`::new`, `std::address_of`, `std::destroy_at`)? Any other safety features I can put in to handle risky operator overloads?
6. Is this approach to copy/move correct? I feel as though I need to be hands-on because the underlying array may have unknown uninitialized fields. Am I doing the right thing about exception safety? I decided I'd rather have the vector appear empty than have it appear full with malformed entries.
7. What should I do, if anything, about an `std::swap` on either data structure?

I'm told this is similar to something like `boost::small_vector`, but I want the `aligned_storage_array` generalized because I want to use it for a number of different static structures later. Also, I would like to learn more about alignment/placement new, forwarding, and launder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static_vector(const static_vector& rhs)
{
    clear(); // Sets m_size to zero for safety
    for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < rhs.m_size; ++pos)
        m_data[pos] = rhs.m_data[pos];
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
}
```

`clear()` is not needed (`m_size` is already zero because of the default member initializer).

**bug:** We are assigning to elements that haven't been constructed yet! We need to use placement new (either through the `emplace` function, or `std::uninitialized_copy_n`) to construct each element in place. The move constructor has the same issue.

---

```
static_vector(static_vector&& rhs)
{
    // Start by clearing sizes to avoid bad data
    // access in the case of an exception
    std::size_t count_self = m_size;
    std::size_t count_rhs = rhs.m_size;
    m_size = 0;
    rhs.m_size = 0;

    // Can't swap because the destination may be uninitialized
    destroy_n(count_self);
    for (std::size_t pos = 0; pos < count_rhs; ++pos)
        m_data[pos] = std::move(rhs.m_data[pos]);
    m_size = count_rhs;
}
```

Same issue as above (assignment to non-constructed elements).

We could call `clear()` to set the size to zero and destroy the elements in `this`.

**bug:** It's incorrect to alter the size of `rhs` like this. Although we have moved from the `rhs` elements, they still "exist", and we need to call their destructors. (Note that unlike `std::vector`, `std::array` isn't empty after a "move").

If we want `rhs` to be empty afterwards, we can call `rhs.clear()` after moving the elements.

---

The copy / move construction / assignment can be simplified quite a bit:

```
static_vector(const static_vector& rhs)
{
    std::uninitialized_copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
}

static_vector& operator=(const static_vector& rhs)
{
    clear();
    std::uninitialized_copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
    return *this;
}

static_vector(static_vector&& rhs)
{
    std::uninitialized_move(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
}

static_vector& operator=(static_vector&& rhs)
{
    clear();
    std::uninitialized_move(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), begin());
    m_size = rhs.m_size;
    return *this;
}
```

---

Swapping is never going to be fast because we're storing the elements on the stack, and have to swap them all in turn. We could write something with `std::swap_ranges`, and then `std::uninitialized_move` any extra elements if there's a size mismatch, but I'd probably just do this:

```
    // member function
    void swap(static_vector& rhs)
    {
        auto temp = std::move(*this);
        *this = std::move(rhs);
        rhs = std::move(temp);
    }

...

// free function in the nonstd namespace
template<class T, std::size_t N>
void swap(static_vector<T, N>& a, static_vector<T, N>& b)
{
    a.swap(b);
}
```

---

I think preventing copy and move (and not defining swap) on `aligned_storage_array` is fine.

---

```
inline T& at(std::size_t pos)
{
    if ((pos < 0) || (pos >= m_size))
    ...
}
```

`pos` is (correctly) unsigned, so `(pos < 0)` isn't needed.

Use the `size_type` typedef for the function argument (same with the other element access functions).

There's no need to use the `inline` keyword for functions defined in a class body.

---

```
    inline iterator begin()                 { return &m_data[0]; }
    inline const_iterator begin()     const { return &m_data[0]; }
    inline iterator end()                   { return &m_data[m_size]; }
    inline const_iterator end()       const { return &m_data[m_size]; }
```

**bug:** This is undefined behaviour. The array elements at `[m_size]` or even `[0]` may not exist. (So the `std::array` implementation may sensibly throw or crash if we try to access them).

We can fix this with:

```
    // in aligned_storage_array:
    T* data()
    {
        return std::launder(
            reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data.data()));
    }

    T const* data() const
    {
        return std::launder(
            reinterpret_cast<T const*>(m_data.data()));
    }

    ...

    // in static_vector:
    iterator begin()                 { return m_data.data(); }
    const_iterator begin()     const { return m_data.data(); }
    iterator end()                   { return m_data.data() + m_size; }
    const_iterator end()       const { return m_data.data() + m_size; }
```

This gives us pointer access, which is what we need for iterators. As long as we only dereference pointers to valid elements, we avoid undefined behaviour (i.e. don't dereference `end()`, and only use `begin()` if `size()` isn't zero).

---

```
    template<typename ...Args>
    inline T& emplace_back(Args&&... args)
    {
        T& result = m_data.bounded_emplace(m_size, args...);
        ...
    }
```

We should use `std::forward` here (it's correctly used in the `aligned_storage_array::emplace` functions).

---

I'm really not very familiar with `std::launder`, so hopefully someone else can comment on that.

Comment: These are great. I have two follow-up questions.


(1) Should I retain the `if (this != std::addressof(rhs))` check in `static_vector`'s copy? I noticed you removed it in your simplication.

(2) Would `std::destroy_n` be a safe/viable alternative to use in the `static_vector` `destroy_n()` function?

Comment: One additional note, after testing. The new move constructor and assignment of the `static_vector` doesn't set the `rhs` structure's `m_size` to zero, which means that that that `rhs` `static_vector` will destruct its (now potentially unknown) contents when going out of scope. Should I add a line to set it to zero in this case and avoid that behavior?

Comment: (1) It's not needed. Copy / swap works for self-assignment too. Note that checking would add overhead for the non-self-assignment cases, which are the ones we want to be faster! (2) Yes.

Comment: Yes. We still need to call destructors on moved-from objects, so directly setting `m_size` to zero is wrong. But if we want the `static_vector` to be empty after move (probably a good design choice), we can call `clear()` on `rhs` just before returning from the constructor / operator.